# Javascript equivalent function for jquery .on() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is equivalent of following jQuery in Javascript:

```
$('.class').on('DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    // do something
  });
```

Comment: `addEventListener()`?

Comment: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: Just to aid research purposes, a link to the Mozilla Developer Network's entry for: [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: addEventListener for IE9+, for older IEs - attachEvent.

Comment: You could check jquery code yourself. Actually it is open source and such. :)

Comment: @IjonTichy I doubt older IEs should be considered when it comes to `DOMNodeRemoved` event.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko that's a good point, but answering the title question it is useful information to give. Moreover as far as I know jquery source code you refer to uses attachEvent to handle events.

Comment: @IjonTichy Not in 2.x branch. Older IE is pure evil that should be exterminated asap. Less we support this sh*t more users update their browser. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own function. For IE9+:

```
function on(selector, event, handler) {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(node) {
        node.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
on('.class', 'DOMNodeRemoved', function(){/*blah*/});
```